# If $\mathrm{{S_n} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \left( {\frac{1}{{{n^6}}} + \frac{{32}}{{{n^6}}} + ... + \frac{1}{n}} \right)}$ find ...

Tags: integration, limits

$S_n=\frac{1}{n^6}\sum^n_{k=1}k^5$ and $T_n=\frac{1}{n^6}\sum^{n-1}_{k=1}k^5$ then what can be said about $S_n+T_n$?:

1. $(S_n + T_n) > \frac{1}{3}$
2. $(S_n + T_n) < \frac{1}{3}$

Which of the following would be correct and why?
I understand that $S_n \to \frac{1}{6}^+$ and that $T_n \to \frac{1}{6}^-$ but I don't understand how is it possible to tell the relation between their sums and $\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: Do you mean that $S_n= \left( {\frac{1}{{{n^6}}} + \frac{{32}}{{{n^6}}} + ... + \frac{1}{n}} \right)$ as $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \left( {\frac{1}{{{n^6}}} + \frac{{32}}{{{n^6}}} + ... + \frac{1}{n}} \right)$ does not depend on $n$.

Comment: Yes it is n tending to infinity. The difference I think is in the order of summations. For T it is $T_n=\frac{1}{n^6}\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}k^5$ for S it is $S_n=\frac{1}{n^6}\sum^{n}_{k=1}k^5$ thats what I infer from it

Comment: @OliverDiaz I think it's to do with integral as a limit of sum

Comment: @protus: Of course. But trying to understand your notation blurs things a little. I mad edits to your OP. Hopefully now is clear.

Comment: @OliverDiaz I think you missed the limit for $n \to \infty$ for S in your edit

Comment: @protus: Your sums are Riemann sums for the integral $\int^1_0x^5\,dx$. One uses the right endpoint of the regular partition, the other the left endpoint.

Answer (score 3):

We have that $S_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^5$ and $T_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{k-1}{n}\right)^5$.

It's evident that the limits of both $S_n$ and $T_n$ are Riemann sum expressions for $\int_0^1 x^5\, dx=\frac{1}{6}$, where $S_n$ is the right hand sum and $T_n$ is the left hand sum.

Since the average of the left hand and right hand Riemann sums is the trapezoidal Riemann sum, we have that $\frac{S_n+T_n}{2}$ is the trapezoidal Riemann sum approximation for $\int_0^1 x^5\, dx$.

However, since $x^5$ is convex on $[0,\infty)$, it is a well known property that the trapezoidal Riemann sum approximation is always greater than the integral of a convex function. Hence, we have that
$$\frac{S_n+T_n}{2}>\int_0^1 x^5\, dx$$
$$\frac{S_n+T_n}{2}>\frac{1}{6}$$
$$\boxed{S_n+T_n>\frac{1}{3}}$$

Answer (score 2):

We have that $S_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^5$ and $T_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{k-1}{n}\right)^5$.

It's evident that the limits of both $S_n$ and $T_n$ are Riemann sum expressions for $\int_0^1 x^5\, dx=\frac{1}{6}$, where $S_n$ is the right hand sum and $T_n$ is the left hand sum.

Since $x^5$ is monotonically increasing, we have that $S_n>\frac{1}{6}$ and $T_n<\frac{1}{6}$.

The question is asking to determine the sign of
$$S_n+T_n-\frac{1}{3}$$
$$=S_n+T_n-2\int_0^1 x^5\, dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^5+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{k-1}{n}\right)^5-2\int_0^1 x^5\, dx$$
It is clear that $\int_0^1 x^5=\sum_{k=1}^n \int_{\frac{k-1}{n}}^{\frac{k}{n}} x^5\, dx=\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^6-\frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{k-1}{n}\right)^6\right)$.
Going back to our expression, we can combine all the summands into one summation since they all have the same bounds,
$$=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k^5}{n^6}+\frac{(k-1)^5}{n^6}-\frac{k^6}{3n^6}+\frac{(k-1)^6}{3n^6}$$
$$=\frac{1}{3n^6}\sum_{k=1}^n 3k^5+3(k-1)^5-k^6+(k-1)^6$$
Shifting the bounds of our summation results in
$$=\frac{1}{3n^6}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 3(k+1)^5+3k^5-(k+1)^6+k^6$$
Note that $k^6-(k+1)^6=-6k^5-15k^4-20k^3-15k^2-6k-1$ while $3(k+1)^5+3k^5=6k^5+15k^4+30k^3+30k^2+15k+3$. Hence, the inner summand is
$$10k^3+15k^2+9k+2>0\forall k\geq 0$$
Since each term of the inner summand is positive, we have that the entire summation is positive. Hence,
$$S_n+T_n-\frac{1}{3}>0$$
$$\boxed{S_n+T_n>\frac{1}{3}}$$